# Bluetooth Push notification for iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, ios-bluetooth

We want Bluetooth notification to our iOS app when I am connecting our device to car bluetooth.

Comment: Could you please explain more what you've tried so far, which research you did, and what you don't understand. As it is now, the question is too broad for this website.

Comment: unable to get. What is your question? Explain as much as possible.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS  Get push notifications whenever the user's phone connects with their phone's Bluetooth.

Comment: @PraveshDubey did you get any solution?

Comment: No, I didn't get any solution.